# Creating java classes and java package on command line using maven

Tags: java, maven

I have created a java spring mvc application using eclipse and i i am running it using java mvn on my command line mvn package and mvn tomcat7:run and everything works out. However, i want to generate a new java package. I have this packages that already exists

[image]

```
com.boilerplate.configs
com.boilerplate.controllers
com.boilerplate.models
com.boilerplate.services
```

are all packages i created while i was on eclipse. Inside each package, there are classes that i have created,for instance there is a class `BoilerplateController.java` inside of controllers.

How can i add a package using for instance `com.boilerplate.aws` using maven or java?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A package is just a directory. Use a file explorer or command line stuff.

In java, you could write

```
new File("src/main/java/com/boilerplate/package2").mkdirs()
```

But you are probably mistaking the concepts here. Use the IDE, such as Eclipse, to write the code, and use mvn to build it and java to execute it.

Comment: `A package is just a directory.` oh okay. I am avoiding eclipse for now, i prefer to work from within notepad++.